# str_repeat reverse (shrink strings)

Tags: php, string

**str_repeat(A, B)** repeat string **A**, **B** times:

```
$string = "This is a " . str_repeat("test", 2) . 
          "! " . str_repeat("hello", 3) . " and Bye!";  

// Return "This is a testtest! hellohellohello and Bye!"
```

I need reverse operation:

```
str_shrink($string, array("hello", "test")); 
// Return "This is a test(x2)! hello(x3) and Bye!" or
//        "This is a [test]x2! [hello]x3 and Bye!"
```

Best and efficient way for create **str_shrink** function?

Comment: Erasing repetitions (words in array), count, and adding a "xT" (times repeated).

I'm thinking use substr_count() or regexp, but I want a efficient way.

Comment: How have you tried that in code?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Try something, if it's too slow, then optimize or try something else.

Comment: I agree, working on a string in php is pretty damn fast. i sometimes get a little lazy with the efficiency for string work because it doesn't matter

Comment: Premature optimization is evil, but... in a scenary with use frequent of str_shrink function (many calls in scripts with high traffic) is better avoid regexp-way compared to strpos-str_replace-way?

Comment: @Manz - Try it. I've updated my post to have the regex-way be as efficient as possible, it will hopefully hold up in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions that I could come up with.

The first uses a regular expression and replaces duplicate matches of the `$needle` string with a single `$needle` string. This is the most vigorously tested version and handles all possibilities of inputs successfully (as far as I know).

```
function str_shrink( $str, $needle)
{
    if( is_array( $needle))
    {
        foreach( $needle as $n)
        {
            $str = str_shrink( $str, $n);   
        }
        return $str;
    }
    $regex = '/(' . $needle . ')(?:' . $needle . ')+/i';
    return preg_replace_callback( $regex, function( $matches) { return $matches[1] . '(x' . substr_count( $matches[0], $matches[1]) . ')'; }, $str);
}
```

The second uses string manipulation to continually replace occurrences of the `$needle` concatenated with itself. Note that this one will fail if `$needle.$needle` occurs more than once in the input string (The first one does not have this problem).

```
function str_shrink2( $str, $needle)
{
    if( is_array( $needle))
    {
        foreach( $needle as $n)
        {
            $str = str_shrink2( $str, $n);   
        }
        return $str;
    }
    $count = 1; $previous = -1;
    while( ($i = strpos( $str, $needle.$needle)) > 0)
    {
        $str = str_replace( $needle.$needle, $needle, $str);
        $count++;
        $previous = $i;
    }
    if( $count > 1)
    {
        $str = substr( $str, 0, $previous) . $needle .'(x' . $count . ')' . substr( $str, $previous + strlen( $needle));
    }
    return $str;
}
```

[See them both in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/parDm4)

**Edit:** I didn't realize that the desired output wanted to include the number of repetitions. I've modified my examples accordingly.

Comment: Just a note - Use the first version, there's a small bug in the second version that I haven't worked out yet.

Comment: I've fixed the second version - They both produce correct output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with:

```
<?php
$string = "This is a testtest! hellohellohello and Bye!";

function str_shrink($string, $array){
    $tr = array();
    foreach($array as $el){
        $n = substr_count($string, $el);
        $tr[$el] = $el.'(x'.$n.')';
        $pattern[] = '/('.$el.'\(x'.$n.'\))+/i';
    }
    return preg_replace($pattern, '${1}', strtr($string,$tr));
}

echo $string;
echo '<br/>';
echo str_shrink($string,array('test','hello'));  //This is a test(x2)! hello(x3) and Bye!
?>
```

I have a second version in order to works with strings:

```
<?php
$string = "This is a testtest! hellohellohello and Bye!";

function str_shrink($string, $array){
    $tr = array();
    $array = is_array($array) ? $array : array($array);
    foreach($array as $el){
        $sN = 'x'.substr_count($string, $el);
        $tr[$el] = $el.'('.$sN.')';
        $pattern[] = '/('.$el.'\('.$sN.'\))+/i';
    }
    return preg_replace($pattern, '${1}', strtr($string,$tr));
}

echo $string;
echo '<br/>';
echo str_shrink($string,array('test','hello'));  //This is a test(x2)! hello(x3) and Bye!
echo '<br/>';
echo str_shrink($string,'test');  //This is a test(x2)! hellohellohello and Bye!
?>
```

Comment: Applying a string that contains the needle causes it to fail, see [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/g1la0m). This is the same problem I'm having with my second version.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with tis one, not tested a lot though

```
function shrink($s, $parts, $mask = "%s(x%d)"){

            foreach($parts as $part){
                    $removed = 0;

                    $regex = "/($part)+/";

                    preg_match_all($regex, $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
                    if(!$matches)
                            continue;

                    foreach($matches[0] as $m){
                            $offset = $m[1] - $removed;
                            $nb = substr_count($m[0], $part);
                            $counter = sprintf($mask, $part, $nb);
                            $s = substr($s, 0, $offset) . $counter . substr($s, $offset + strlen($m[0]));
                            $removed += strlen($m[0]) - strlen($part);    
                    }

            }
            return $s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept it short:

```
function str_shrink($haystack, $needles, $match_case = true) {
    if (!is_array($needles)) $needles = array($needles);
    foreach ($needles as $k => $v) $needles[$k] = preg_quote($v, '/');
    $regexp = '/(' . implode('|', $needles) . ')+/' . ($match_case ? '' : 'i');
    return preg_replace_callback($regexp, function($matches) {
        return $matches[1] . '(x' . (strlen($matches[0]) / strlen($matches[1])) . ')';
    }, $haystack);
}
```

The behavior of cases like `str_shrink("aaa", array("a", "a(x3)"))` is it returns `"a(x3)"`, which I thought was more likely intended if you're specifying an array. For the other behavior, giving a result of `"a(x3)(x1)"`, call the function with each needle individually.

If you don't want multiples of one to get "(x1)" change:

```
        return $matches[1] . '(x' . (strlen($matches[0]) / strlen($matches[1])) . ')';
```

to:

```
        $multiple = strlen($matches[0]) / strlen($matches[1]);
        return $matches[1] . (($multiple > 1) ? '(x' . $multiple . ')' : '');
```

Comment: Appending a string that contains the needle causes it to fail, see [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xA0NWX).

Comment: @nickb: Huh? Because of "test(x1)ing"? That's not a fail. OP didn't specify he wanted it on word boundaries or something, though it would be simple to change it to `$regexp = '/\b(' . implode('|', $needles) . ')+\b/' . ($match_case ? '' : 'i');` if that's the matching criteria that's wanted instead. I already said how to disable or enable the "(x1)".

Comment: Word boundaries are irrelevant for the problem statement - `testing` contains one of the needles, but that needle is not a repetition, and should therefore remain untouched.

Comment: @nickb: >not a repetition. Can't you read? OP did not specify which behavior was preferred, so I wrote code for both.

Comment: Wow. OK, let's try it this way. The first behavior (i.e. the one my demo shows) **MAKES NO SENSE**, as `test` is the repeated word, not `testing`. For `test` to be identified, the string `testtest` must be found somewhere in the input. Otherwise, **ANY** other string that contains `test` **ISN'T** a repetition of the word `test`, and should be **LEFT ALONE**. Maybe that makes sense. If not, you must not be able to read the OP.

Comment: @nickb: >"test is the repeated word" >"repetition of the word test" Nowhere does OP say it's supposed to be only for "words". It's a string function. Also, `str_repeat("foo", 1)` is valid, and OP said they wanted the reverse operation, so I implemented the same lower bound. But since the intention was obviously ambiguous, I also gave the very easy instructions for changing it to the other behavior if that was preferred. If you can't read beyond the first paragraph of my solution that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very direct, single-regex technique and you don't need to collect the words in the string in advance.

There will be some fringe cases to mitigate which are not represented in the sample input, but as for the general purpose of this task, I reckon this is the way that I'd script this in my project.

1. Match (and capture) any full word that is repeated one or more times.
2. Match the contiguous repetitions of the word.
3. Replace the fullstring match (substring of multiple words) with the captured first instance of the word.
4. Before returning the replacement string for re-insertion, add the desired formatting and calculate the number of repetitions by dividing the fullstring length by the captured string's length.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2VbL3))

```
$string = "This is a " . str_repeat("test", 2) . 
          "!\n" . str_repeat("hello", 3) . " and Bye!\n" .
          "When I sleep, the thought bubble says " . str_repeat("zz", 3) . ".";

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~\b(\w+?)\1+\b~',
         function($m) {
             return "[{$m[1]}](" . (strlen($m[0]) / strlen($m[1])) . ")";
         },
         $string
     );
```

Output:

```
This is a [test](2)!
[hello](3) and Bye!
When I sleep, the thought bubble says [z](6).
```

---

For a whitelist of needles, this adaptation to my above code does virtually the same job.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CiAWu))

```
function str_shrink($string, $needles) {
    // this escaping is unnecessary if only working with alphanumeric characters
    $needles = array_map(function($needle) {
        return preg_quote($needle, '~');
    }, $needles);

    return preg_replace_callback(
         '~\b(' . implode('|', $needles) . ')\1+\b~',
         function($m) {
             return "[{$m[1]}](" . (strlen($m[0]) / strlen($m[1])) . ")";
         },
         $string
     );
}

echo str_shrink($string, ['test', 'hello']);
```

Output:

```
This is a [test](2)!
[hello](3) and Bye!
When I sleep, the thought bubble says zzzzzz.
```